# jQuery HTMLCollection, tag stripping

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm getting some POST data via AJAX as XML, and am trying to load it into a textarea using jQuery, and am running into some problems.

The XML looks like this (stripped down, showing only the problem elements):

```
<Entry>
    <Title>A <i>Title</i> with italics.</Title>
    <Abstract>An abstract, which <i>also</i> may have italics</Abstract>
</Entry>
```

I've converted this XML into a jQuery object using `$dom = $(xml)`, where `xml` is the XML string above. For some reason, jQuery seems to be inconsistent about `.text()` versus `.html()`. I think the problem has to do with an HTMLCollection (that's what logging the object shows), but I'm not sure.

`$dom.find('Title').text();` works as I want it to, turning title into "`A <i>Title</i> with italics`." Doing the same thing on the abstract (`$dom.find('Abstract').text()`) strips the `<i>` tags entirely, resulting in "`An abstract, which also may have italics`".

Frustratingly, doing thing with `.html()` isn't consistent either!

```
$dom.find('Title').html();    #=> 'A &lt;Title&gt;, with italics'
$dom.find('Abstract').html()  #=> 'An abstract, which <i>also</i> may have...'
```

Any ideas as to what the problem is? The XML is untyped, though I don't think that should make a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say `html()` won't work with XML & `<title>` works with `.text()` because its a known DOM element, rename the tag to something else & the inner HTML will be stripped as with `<abstract>`.

You can enclose the node values that contain HTML in CDATA sections & use `parseXML()`;

```
var xml = "<Entry><Title><![CDATA[A <i>Title</i> with italics.]]></Title><Abstract><![CDATA[An abstract, which <i>also</i> may have italics]]></Abstract></Entry>";

$dom = $($.parseXML(xml));
alert( $dom.find('Title').text() );
alert( $dom.find('Abstract').text() );
```

Comment: I had a realization while eating lunch that it might have something to do with the fact that Title is an HTML element. The CDATA helps a lot...thanks!